# Is there a way to exclude / override one of included URL paths?

Tags: django

I need to exclude or override one of included url paths.

I have used the `django.contrib.auth` package to implement registration and login as well as password recovery, but I decided to implement password changing myself. However, the url paths don't seem to be easily overriden.

This is my urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/password_change', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls',)),
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

I thought that including this `path('accounts/password_change', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),` line before the one with the include operation would solve the problem, but it seems that the pattern matching function traverses the included urls first, and only then checks the remaining urls.

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

To show you where my problem lies, I added another dummy url: `accounts/change` which is not under `django.contrib.auth.urls`. I also added the same url after the library include, as suggested in comments.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/password_change', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),
    path('accounts/change', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', )),
    path('accounts/password_change', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Now, visiting `/accounts/change` triggers the correct view, but `/accounts/password_change` still renders the one from the library.

Comment: Yes, you can, just add your add path after this (library one).

Comment: @sonus21
This doesn't work. No matter if I include the 
`path('accounts/password_change', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),`
before or after the library include, the view from the library gets fired off.

Comment: can you show me your code? It should be working.